# Newbe: Android Studio: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to **Android Studio**.

When I create a new project with *Blank Activity*, the application runs fine on my handset.

However when I create a new project with *Navigation Drawer Activity*, the application doesn't work and shows me the following:

1- Wherever `R` is located in the `MainActivity.java`, it is red-colored with the following message:

> Cannot resolved symbol 'R'

2- In the **Messages Gradle Build** tab:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> Error: [C:\ ...\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\24.1.1\AndroidManifest.xml:21] Invalid instruction 'overrideLibrary', valid instructions are : REMOVE,REPLACE,STRICT

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hwc.mst.mobilesharingtool" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.hwc.mst.mobilesharingtool.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is what I did so far:

1- `Build` -> `Clean project`

2- `Tool` -> `Android` -> `Sync Project with Gradle Files`

3- Check in `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `app` -> `Properties` (Tab) that:

(i)  Compile Sdk Version = API 24: Android 7.0, and ..

(ii) Build Tools Version = 21.1.1

Step 1, 2 & 3 didn't change a thing and still unable to run the app !

How to proceed from here to fix this problem ?!

Comment: gradle can get temperamental some times, have you tried 
1. doing a clean project or
2. locating and deleting the .gradle folder and trying to do a a fresh gradle build.

Comment: And do you have the android api 24 support libraries installed?

Comment: @Aaron: please check the question update, I already did step-1 and yet nothing. As for step-2: do you mean the Gradle folder in the Plugin folder in Android Studio installation folder ?! .. Also, According to SDK Manager, the Android 7.0 (API 24) is installed. Did you something else ?! Thank you

Comment: Try to clean and restart AS as well. Sometimes restart might help.

Comment: Nope in your system you should have a .gradle folder, in Windows it's usually under C://Users/{Yourname}/.gradle. Yourname is just the name of the system ie aaron, or owner for example

Comment: @Aaron: I closed the IDE, deleted the .gradle folder, started the IDE and ran the app, yet same error came up !! .. what could I do next ?!

Comment: open your sdk manager and check you have the tools, support-libraries and repositories for api 24

Comment: @Aaron: I installed the Android 7.0 (API 24),  but still having the same issue !

Comment: Your testing this on your phone, check your phone specs and see if they match, the project could be specifying commands your phones system cannot perform.

Comment: @Aaron: I have Nexus-7 which runs `Cynongenmode OS` (based on `Android 4.3.1`). The app runs fine on it with **minSDK 18** and **targetSDK 19** (as tested in eclipse). Now, as it was not included, I added `uses-sdk` tag to the `AndroidManifest.xml` with the same values. But I failed again to run the app !! ..

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out what was the problem exactly. So, I did the following:

**Step(1)**: Uninstalled Android-studio completely from my machine (following Harry James's [instructions](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/uninstallreinstall-android-studio) )

**Step(2)**: Download and installed Android Studio again

**Step(3)**: There is no step 3

Now, everything works fine.

---

P.S: Big credit to @Aaron for the troubleshooting